# Adding a button to the ribbon of a publishing page

Tags: ribbon, publishing-page

What is te CommandUIDefinition Location for adding a button to the Page Actions section of a publishing page?  I looked on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543.aspx) but I could only find Web Part Pages and Wiki Pages.

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of those is what you want I think, if you view source on a normal publishing page you can see IDs like :-

```
id="Ribbon.WikiPageTab"
```

even though it isn't a wiki page...

I am fairly sure that in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.XML you should be looking at:-

```
<Tab Id="Ribbon.WikiPageTab" Sequence="1000" Command="WikiPageTab" Description="" Title="$Resources:core,TabWikiPageTitle;">
```

The Title attribute of that node refers to a resource file value which in English is "Page"